# Vuejs: Hide only a row from a dynamic table

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to replace an `td` for an `input` on a `table` with a `click event`.

But when I click I convert all rows to inputs and I just want to convert only  that one that I'm clicking

```html
<tr v-for="student in students">
  <td :id="student.id" v-if="isEditing == false">{{student.name}}</td>
  <td v-if="isEditing"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
  <td>{{student.lastname}}</td>
  <td>{{student.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{student.address}}</td>
  <td>{{student.city}}</td>
  <td>{{student.country}}</td>
  <td>
    <!-- Boton para activar la edicion, se oculta al darle click / Se muestra al darle click a guardar-->
    <button v-if="!isEditing" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-sm" title="Editar student" @click="editReact(student.id)"><i class="fas fa-pen" title="Editar student"></i></button>
    <!-- Boton para eliminar registro, se oculta al darle click a editiar -->
    <button v-if="!isEditing" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" title="Eliminar student" @click="drop(student.id, student.nombre, student.apellido)">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash" title="Eliminar student"></i>
                            </button>
    <!--Boton para Guardar la edicion la edicion se oculta al darle click-->
    <button v-if="isEditing" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm" title="Guardar" @click="editReact(student.id)" @click="store"><i class="fas fa-save" title="Guardar"></i></button>
    <!-- Boton para cancelar guardard/ Se muestra al activar edicion-->
    <button v-if="isEditing" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-sm" @click="editReact(false)"><i class="fas fa-ban" title="Cancelar"></i></button>

  </td>
</tr>
```

My data and methods

```
  data() {
      return {
          isEditing: false
      };
  }

  methods: {
    store() {
      console.log('saving..');
      this.isEditing = false;
    },
    editReact(action = true){
      this.isEditing = action;
      console.log('editing');
    },
```

Basically I'm just switching  `isEditing` property to `true` or `false` with a method that I call  with the event `@click`. If I want to render or not some elements (buttons, input,  and td). But affects me all rows **I want that affects  me only one row, the whole row!**

I'm filling the table with axios consulting a database with backend in php. **The Vuejs content its a component using cdn vuejs. Is not vue-cli or mix/webpack**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property called `currentId` which refers to the current edited element initialized with `-1` and update when you click on a row :

```
<button v-if="isEditing" class="btn 
btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm" title="Guardar"
 @click="editReact(student.id, true)" >
```

```
 data() {
      return {
          isEditing: false,
         currentId:-1
      };
  }

  methods: {
    store() {
      console.log('saving..');
      this.isEditing = false;
      this.currentId=-1;
    },
    editReact( id,action = true){
      this.isEditing = action;
      this.currentId=id;
    },
```

then replace `v-if="isEditing"` with `v-if="isEditing && student.id===currentId"`

Comment: You can simply use `isEditing` as (initially empty) string and populate it with the active row id, rather than having two props. And possibly rename it to `editingRowId`, for sanity.

Comment: Yes you're right, i kept that property because he needs it somewhere, but `v-if="student.id===currentId"` is sufficient